# Converting varchar to date displays 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert my column into a DATE format.
It is currently in varchar and displays as: 12/06/2013

I run the following query;

```
UPDATE dispatch
   SET dispatchdate = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dispatchdate, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y');

ALTER TABLE dispatch
      CHANGE dispatchdate dispatchdate date;
```

However after running this query, it displays my data as: 0000-00-00

I am trying to change it so that it will **display as DD-MM-YYYY** not YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is how MySQL displays the date.  It is not intended for aesthetic purposes, it is intended to be functional.

Answer (score 0):

`0000-00-00` is mysql's special way of displaying a "zero" or "dummy" [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Like many of mysql's oddities, you learn to live with it and I suggest you:

```
UPDATE dispatch SET
dispatchdate = null
WHERE dispatchdate = '0000-00-00'
```

Or set to whatever value works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build a scratch column:  you cannot change the data type of a column in place, and expect to keep the data.  It just won't work.

So

- Add a new datetime column, maybe named `tmp_dispatchdate`
- Use the query you've written to write the datetime value into that column
- After confirming that the data converted correctly, drop `dispatchdate`
- Rename `tmp_dispatchdate` to `dispatchdate`

If you have a primary key on the table in question, you can do all the "middle" work in a temp table, if you prefer, using the PK to reference the right record.   But you'll still have to drop a column and add a column to do what you're trying to do.